# Is there a multilingual dictionary which translate many words in the same time?

Tags: open-source, dictionary

I want a dictionary which translates many words. For example English-German, English-Swedish dictionary which translates 1000 entries or words in the same time. I don't want to translators like google or microsoft because I don't want to translate sentences just words but translate accurately.

Comment: Can you program? There is a Python library for almost every need: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-translate/

Comment: Are you looking for a web app – or for a program natively running on your OS (which OS then)?

Comment: It does not matter if it is a web app or an offline application just need to translate long list words in the same time.

Comment: Did you try Babylon